# After compiling BlueZ 5.43 from source, bluetooth -v still returns 5.41

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, bluez

Could you please suggest why BlueZ 5.43 isn't installed on Ubuntu MATE 16.10 ?

Here is what I did

1. got http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.43.tar.xz
2. installed dependencies via `sudo apt-get install build-essential glib2.0 libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev`
3. unpacked archive, ran `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`

make install gave following output

```
make --no-print-directory install-am
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c client/bluetoothctl monitor/btmon tools/hciattach tools/hciconfig tools/hcitool tools/hcidump tools/rfcomm tools/rctest tools/l2test tools/l2ping tools/sdptool tools/ciptool tools/bccmd tools/bluemoon tools/hex2hcd tools/mpris-proxy '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c client/bluetoothctl /usr/local/bin/bluetoothctl
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c monitor/btmon /usr/local/bin/btmon
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hciattach /usr/local/bin/hciattach
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hciconfig /usr/local/bin/hciconfig
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hcitool /usr/local/bin/hcitool
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hcidump /usr/local/bin/hcidump
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/rfcomm /usr/local/bin/rfcomm
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/rctest /usr/local/bin/rctest
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/l2test /usr/local/bin/l2test
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/l2ping /usr/local/bin/l2ping
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/sdptool /usr/local/bin/sdptool
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/ciptool /usr/local/bin/ciptool
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/bccmd /usr/local/bin/bccmd
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/bluemoon /usr/local/bin/bluemoon
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hex2hcd /usr/local/bin/hex2hcd
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/mpris-proxy /usr/local/bin/mpris-proxy
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c src/bluetoothd obexd/src/obexd '/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c src/bluetoothd /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c obexd/src/obexd /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/obexd
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/cups/backend'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c profiles/cups/bluetooth '/usr/local/lib/cups/backend'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c profiles/cups/bluetooth /usr/local/lib/cups/backend/bluetooth
 /bin/mkdir -p '/etc/dbus-1/system.d'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/bluetooth.conf '/etc/dbus-1/system.d'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/dbus-1/services'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 obexd/src/org.bluez.obex.service '/usr/share/dbus-1/services'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/org.bluez.service '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tools/hciattach.1 tools/hciconfig.1 tools/hcitool.1 tools/hcidump.1 tools/rfcomm.1 tools/rctest.1 tools/l2ping.1 tools/sdptool.1 tools/ciptool.1 tools/bccmd.1 tools/hid2hci.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/bluetoothd.8 '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/udev/rules.d'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tools/97-hid2hci.rules '/lib/udev/rules.d'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/systemd/system'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/bluetooth.service '/lib/systemd/system'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/systemd/user'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 obexd/src/obex.service '/usr/lib/systemd/user'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/udev'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c tools/hid2hci '/lib/udev'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hid2hci /lib/udev/hid2hci
```

After restart `bluetoothd -v` still gives `5.41`

Output of `type -a bluetoothd` is `bluetoothd is /usr/sbin/bluetoothd` and `/usr/local/bin/bluetoothd` is not found.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `type -a bluetoothd`, and `/usr/local/bin/bluetoothd -v`

Comment: @muru Updated !

Comment: huh, sorry, it seems the file is actually `/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd`. You'll probably need to symlink it to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @muru if you post your comments as answer I'll be happy to accept it